# Get next BACHNUMB for econnect taPopRcptHdrInsert

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, econnect, dynamics-gp

How do I get the next BACHNUMB for the Dynamics GP eConnect proc taPopRcptHdrInsert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no NEXT batch number like Next Document Number, you have to provide batch id, if this already exist in GP all is fine if not e-connect will create new id.